# Can vs Could usage differences

Tags: modal-verbs

> 1). His dance was unbelievable! I don't know if I **can do** do it.
>
> 2). His dance was unbelievable! I don't know if I **could do** it.

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is to be used if the speaker is actually going to try to do it.

The second is to be used in the hypothetical situation, that is, if the speaker has no intention of trying to do it.

Comment: Got it. But is there any possibility for the second sentence to represent past ability?

Comment: No, then that would be "I don't know if I could have done it."

Comment: “I don’t know if I could do it anymore.”  I could do it when I was younger, but maybe not anymore, being older.

Comment: @gnasher729 if that's what you intend it to mean, then it would be "I don't know if I can do it any more."

Answer (score 0):

Can and could can be used in different situations, such as possibility, ability, permission, requests, offers, and suggestions. The can and could here are used to express ability here, so I'll just focus on it here, if you have any doubts about the other usages, you can tell me in the comments.

## Using can/could to talk about ability

The difference between can/can't and could/couldn't is the tense.

We use **can** and **can't** to talk about the ability to do something at a specific time in the *present* or *future*:

> I **can** see you.
> Help! I **can't** breathe!

We use **could** and **couldn't** to talk about the *past*:

> She **could** speak several languages, but she forget most of them now.
>
> They **couldn't** dance very well.

However, if you take  a closer look, this is not the situation in the example:

> His dance was unbelievable! I don't know if I **can/could** do it.

The difference here is that **could** can be used to say that someone **had the ability or opportunity** to do something, but **did not do it**:

> She **could learn** Swahili, but she didn't want to.
> I **could dance** all night.

Consequently, the first one is used if the speaker wants to really try the unbelievable dance.

The second one is used when the speaker doesn't intend to try doing it.

## Attribution

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/can-and-could

Answer (score 0):

> His dance was unbelievable! I don't know if I can do do it.

This implies the person is unable to physically perform the dance.

> His dance was unbelievable! I don't know if I could do it.

This implies the person is unable to make a public display in front of a crowd of people. As in stage fright.